# How to Make a Div transparent with background color

Tags: html, forms, css

i want to make a div transparent who have `backgound-color:#5A7D00`.
Actually i want to achieve this result which i want

[image]

but i am not able to achieve this.Please help me with some code to achieve (avoid res strips)

Comment: What is a res strip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the color to rbg so you can use it with the `rgba()` property.

In this case, what you are after is:

```
background-color: rgba(90, 125, 0, 0.5);
```

The last of those 4 values being the opacity level (`0.5`)

Answer (score 1):

You must convert the Hex Color Format to RBG Color format as this format includes Alpha Transparency. Which allows us to make only parent container transparent without changing the transparency of the child containers. In RBG format first 3 values are RBG color values and fourth is the Opacity value ranging between 0 to 1.

So your code should look like :

```
background-color: rgba(90, 125, 0, 0.5);
```

Comment: I'm curious why you post an almost exact duplicate answer 30 minutes after the original.

Comment: I just wanted to give a better understanding that why he should use RBG format.